# Gutenberg add rich text button to editor, button not appearing

Tags: wordpress, api, text, wysiwyg, wordpress-gutenberg

I am following the tutorial here - https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/format-api/

Step 1 - register a new format, this works ok and I can see my new format type in the console

Step 2 - I've added the code to my-custom-format.js to make the button appear and added the corresponding wp-element and wp-editor packages to the dependencies array in the PHP file as instructed.

php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My custom format
 */

function my_custom_format_script_register() {
    wp_register_script(
        'my-custom-format-js',
        plugins_url( 'my-custom-format.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-rich-text',  )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_format_script_register' );

function my_custom_format_enqueue_assets_editor() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-format-js' );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_custom_format_enqueue_assets_editor' );
```

JS file

```
( function( wp ) {
    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-custom-format/sample-output', {
            title: 'Sample output',
            tagName: 'samp',
            className: null,
        }
    );
    var MyCustomButton = function( props ) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            wp.editor.RichTextToolbarButton, {
                icon: 'editor-code',
                title: 'Sample output',
                onClick: function() {
                    props.onChange( wp.richText.toggleFormat(
                        props.value,
                        { type: 'my-custom-format/sample-output' }
                    ) );
                },
                isActive: props.isActive,
            }
        );
    }
    wp.richText.registerFormatType(
        'my-custom-format/sample-output', {
            title: 'Sample output',
            tagName: 'samp',
            className: null,
            edit: MyCustomButton,
        }
    );
} )( window.wp );
```

Do I need to install the @wordpress/rich-text module in order for this to work?

Comment: I fixed this.  I had 'my-custom-format/sample-output' registered twice.  In addition I had put the plugin within my theme. If you are extending the Block Editor for your theme you use the get_template_directory_uri() function instead of plugins_url().